# Passing rest of the codes as callback function

Tags: javascript

In a middle of already completed javascript function, you want to call a new async function. So you need to pass, "rest of the code" as a callback function as parameter to this new function.

```
function sample() {
    alert("a bunch of codes");

    alert("another a bunch of codes");
}
```

I have to change the function as below.

```
function sample() {
    alert("a bunch of codes");

    var cb = function () {
        alert("another a bunch of codes");
    };

    newFunction(cb);
}
```

What if I want to add another function that has to wait first one ? Then I got numerous multiple levels of callback functions to the wait another..

So what is the best practice on ES5 ?

Answer (score 1):

In ES5, just like you said you have to nest multiple callbacks inside each other.

Example:

```
function myFunction2(){
    console.log(2);

  let myFunction = () => {
    console.log(1);
    }

  myFunction();
}
myFunction2();
// OUTPUT
// 2
// 1
```

ES6 also provides a new alternative, [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Example:

```
let myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function(){
    resolve(1);
  }, 250);
});

console.log(2);
myPromise.then((successMessage) => {
  console.log(successMessage);
});
// OUTPUT
// 2
// 1
```

ES8 has provides an even better alternative(although it is just syntactic sugar based on promises) but you can use [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) functions with await.

Example:

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x);
    }, 2000);
  });
}


async function add1(x) {
  const a = await resolveAfter2Seconds(20);
  const b = await resolveAfter2Seconds(30);
  return x + a + b;
}

add1(10).then(v => {
  console.log(v);  // prints 60 after 4 seconds.
});
```

Keep in mind though, that you probably need to use Babel to transpile your js in order to be compatible with all browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know there are some solutions after ES5, but I need a tricky or a smart solution on ES5.

Comment: @KnowGe I believe there are not any other workarounds besides callback hell in ES5, that's why those features were added later in order to resolve this issue.